# How to test for p-value with groups/filters in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks like the example below. (sorry if it's too long, not sure what's acceptable/needed).

I have used the following code to calculate the median and IQR of each time difference (tdif) between tests (testno):

```
data %>% group_by(testno) %>% filter(type ==1) %>%
     summarise(Median = median(tdif), IQR= IQR(tdif), n= n(), .groups = 'keep') -> result
```

I have done this for each category of 'type' (coded as 1 - 10), which brought me to the added table (bottom).

My question is, if it is possible to:

1. Do this an easier way (without the filters? So I can do this all in 1 run), and
2. Is it possible run a test for p-value with all the groups/filters?

   ```
   data <- read.table(header=T, text= '
   PID  time  tdif testno type
   3   205     0      1    1
   4    77     0      1    1
   4    85     8      2    1
   4   126    41      3    1
   4   165    39      4    1  
   4   202    37      5    1
   4   238    36      6    1
   4   272    34      7    1
   4   277     5      8    1
   4   370    93      9    1
   4   397    27     10    1
   4   452    55     11    1
   4   522    70     12    1
   4   529     7     13    1
   4   608    79     14    1
   4   651    43     15    1
   4   655     4     16    1
   4   713    58     17    1
   4   804    91     18    1
   4   900    96     19    1
   4   944    44     20    1
   4   979    35     21    1
   4  1015    36     22    1
   4  1051    36     23    1
   4  1077    26     24    1
   4  1124    47     25    1
   4  1162    38     26    1
   4  1222    60     27    1
   4  1334   112     28    1
   4  1383    49     29    1
   4  1457    74     30    1
   4  1506    49     31    1
   4  1590    84     32    1
   4  1768   178     33    1
   4  1838    70     34    1
   4  1880    42     35    1
   4  1915    35     36    1
   4  1973    58     37    1
   4  2017    44     38    1
   4  2090    73     39    1
   4  2314   224     40    1
   4  2381    67     41    1
   4  2433    52     42    1
   4  2484    51     43    1
   4  2694   210     44    1
   4  2731    37     45    1
   4  2792    61     46    1
   4  2958   166     47    1
   5    48     0      1    3
   5   111    63      2    3
   5   699   588      3    3
   5  1077   378      4    3
   6   -43     0      1    3
   8    67     0      1    1
   8   168   101      2    1
   8   314   146      3    1
   8   368    54      4    1
   8   586   218      5    1
   10   639     0      1    6
   13  -454     0      1    3
   13  -384    70      2    3
   13  -185   199      3    3
   13   193   378      4    3
   13   375   182      5    3
   13   564   189      6    3
   13   652    88      7    3
   13   669    17      8    3
   13   718    49      9    3
   14   704     0      1    8
   15  -165     0      1    3
   15  -138    27      2    3
   15  1335  1473      3    3
   16   168     0      1    6
   18 -1329     0      1    3
   18 -1177   152      2    3
   18 -1071   106      3    3
   18  -945   126      4    3
   18  -834   111      5    3
   18  -719   115      6    3
   18  -631    88      7    3
   18  -497   134      8    3
   18  -376   121      9    3
   18  -193   183     10    3
   18   -78   115     11    3
   18   -13    65     12    3
   18   100   113     13    3
   18   196    96     14    3
   18   552   356     15    3
   18   650    98     16    3
   18   737    87     17    3
   18   804    67     18    3
   18   902    98     19    3
   18   983    81     20    3
   18  1119   136     21    3
   19   802     0      1    1
   19  1593   791      2    1
   26   314     0      1    8
   26   389    75      2    8
   26   597   208      3    8
   33   639     0      1    6
   ```

Added table (values differ from example data, because this isn't the complete set).

[image: Values differ from example, because example isn't the complete data]

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding correctly, but did you want `group_by(testno, type)` instead, and remove the `filter`? As for p-value, please explain further what you are testing for.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that.. Yes, group_by(testno, type) without a filter was what i was looking for. Also, I want to test if there is a significant difference between each type and each tdif.

Comment: stackoverflow is mostly focused on programming and not choice of statistical test...do you know what test you want to use or how you want to approach? you might want to run your code, create medians/IQRs as intended, and make a new post with the result on CrossValidated (see topics [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). There they can provide more specific recommendations regarding modeling/testing...

Comment: Thanks alot, still new to all this. Will check that out, thank you verry much for the help!